# mysql_insert_id not working - cant´echo variable that has mysql_insert_id()

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a table with an `AUTO INCREMENT` column (Id, primary key), and have done the following php code:

```
    $med="MED0x";
    $sql=" INSERT INTO Inscricoes2 (`Nome`,`Nome Clinico`, `Numero Cedula`, `Email`, `Descricao`) VALUES ('$nome_completo', '$nome_clinico', '$numero_cedula', '$email' , '$comentario') " ;
    $num=mysql_insert_id($con);
    $resultado=$med . $num;
    echo "$resultado";
```

But it doesnt echo anything, and an error appears. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you are never executing the query, hence there is no insert id.

```
mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_insert_id($con);
```

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)